# Problema com hasNext() Java

Tags: java, matriz, método

Olá,
Estou com um problema, eu faço um Scanner a um ficheiro txt, depois invoco um método para ir contar as linhas deste ficheiro, depois de me retornar o número de linhas (para dar o tamanho à String Array equaçoes), eu quero novamente voltar a percorrer o ficheiro para ir tratar do resto dos problemas, mas quando vai a entrar no `while (lerFicheiro.hasNext())` salta logo fora, porque o hasNext já está a false.

Aqui fica o código

```
static  double[][] LerFicheiro () throws FileNotFoundException{
    String ficheiro = "ficheiro_teste.txt";
    Scanner lerFicheiro = new Scanner(new File(ficheiro));
    double[][] matrizValores = new double[1][5];
    String aux;
    int num = 0;
    int contador = 0; // variavel auxiliar para contar a linha que está a ser percorrida
    int numLinhas = numeroLinhasMatriz(lerFicheiro);
    String[] equacoes = new String[num];

    while (lerFicheiro.hasNext()) { //enquanto o ficheiro tiver conteudo, vamos percorrer linha a linha
        aux = lerFicheiro.nextLine();
        if (!aux.isEmpty() && aux.length() > 0) {
            aux = aux.toUpperCase();
            if (aux.contains("Z")){
                aux = lerFicheiro.nextLine();
            }         
        int posX1 = aux.indexOf("X");            
        int posX2 = aux.indexOf("X", posX1+1);
        int posB = aux.indexOf("=");
        String valorX1 = valoresX(posX1, aux); //valor do X1 no ficheiro
        String valorX2 = valoresX(posX2, aux); //valor do X2 no ficheiro
        String valorB = matrizInsereB(posB, aux); //valor do B no ficheiro
        /*System.out.println("x1 " + j);
        System.out.println("x2 " + k);
        System.out.println("b "+ b);*/
        String equacao = "";
        if(valorX1.equals("1")){
            valorX1 = "x";
        }
        if(valorX2.equals("0")){
            equacao = valorX1 + valorB + " y_0";
        }
        else if (valorX1.equals("0")){
            equacao = "(" + valorB + "/" + valorX2 + ")";
        }else {
            equacao = "("+ valorX1 + "/" + valorX2 + ")*x+(" + valorB + "/" + valorX2 + ")";
        }      
            equacoes[contador] = equacao;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < equacoes.length; i++){
        System.out.println("posicao "+i +" "+equacoes[i]);
    }
    return matrizValores;
}
static int numeroLinhasMatriz(Scanner ler) {
    String aux;
    int nFuncoes = 0; 
    while (ler.hasNext()) {
        aux = ler.nextLine();
        if (aux.contains("=") || aux.contains("≤")) {
            nFuncoes++;
        }
        if (aux.contains("Z")){
            nFuncoes--;
        }
    } 
    return nFuncoes;
}
```

Se me puderem ajudar agradecia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) não disponibiliza nenhum método que permita voltar ao inicio.

A única forma de fazer isso é voltar a criar um novo objecto *Scanner*, faça isso após a linha `int numLinhas = numeroLinhasMatriz(lerFicheiro);`

```
int numLinhas = numeroLinhasMatriz(lerFicheiro);
lerFicheiro = new Scanner(new File(ficheiro));
```

Ou crie um novo ao chamar o método:

```
int numLinhas = numeroLinhasMatriz(new Scanner(new File(ficheiro)));
```

<sub>Nota:

Você está a declarar um array com 0 elementos.

Julgo a linha `String[] equacoes = new String[num];` deveria ser `String[] equacoes = new String[numLinhas];`</sub>

Comment: Já tinha tentado dessa forma, mas queria arranjar uma forma de não ter que alterar o nome do ficheiro mais que uma vez.

Comment: Veja a resposta do @renan.

Answer (score 2):

Como alternativa à forma que está fazendo, pode utilizar o método [**`Files#readAllLines()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) que já faz a leitura de todas as linhas no arquivo e retorna um objeto **`List<String>`**. Isso vai dispensar o uso do `while` e será preciso ler o arquivo uma única vez, posteriormente você pode contar as linhas e obter cada uma delas por meio dos métodos da interface [**`List`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) .

```
Path localDoArquivo = Paths.get("D:\\foo.txt");
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(localDoArquivo, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Se quiser saber o número de linhas, pode usar o método [**`size()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29):

```
int numeroDeLinhas = linhas.size();
```

Se quiser obter o conteúdo de uma determinada linha, pode usar o método [**`get()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29):

```
String conteudoDaLinhaTres = linhas.get(3);
```